# How to customize response in Spring Integration using WebFlux when a specific error occurs?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-webflux, spring-integration-dsl

I'm trying to work out a `WebClient` based approach to handling and enrichment using a sub-flow on a `WebFlux.outboundGateway` call.

My intent is to handle the case where an HTTP/404 occurs on the remote end. In that case, I will handle the error with a known document which can be handled down-stream and routed appropriately.

```
.enrich( e ->
    e.requestSubFlow(
        sf -> sf.handle(
                WebFlux.outboundGateway("http://example.com/entity/name/{entityName}")
                    .uriVariable("entityName", "payload")
                    .httpMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                    .expectedResponseType(String.class),
                ec -> ec.customizeMonoReply(
                    (message,mono) ->
                        mono.onErrorResume(
                            WebClientResponseException.NotFound.class,
                            Mono.just("{ \"id\": -1, \"name\": null }")
                                .flatMap(s -> 
                                    ServerResponse.ok()
                                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                                        .bodyValue(s)
                                )
                        )
                )
            )
    )
    .headerExpression("result", "payload")
)
```

What I'm getting is a compilation error similar to the following:

```
The method onErrorResume(Class<E>, Function<? super E,? extends Mono<? extends capture#3-of ?>>) in the type Mono<capture#3-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<WebClientResponseException.NotFound>, Mono<Object>)
```

I don't even know if I am approaching this correctly. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

In order to help with this I've posted the entire code https://github.com/djgraff209/so68637283.

EDIT 8/6:

Thanks to @artem-bilan for feedback on this. First point was that the second argument to `onErrorResume` was not a function. I have corrected that.

Next up, the exception match turned out to be incorrect. A generic `WebClientResponseException` was being thrown rather than a more specific `WebClientResponseException.NotFound` which is what I was hoping for.

I updated the logic as follows. This code is available on the referenced GitHub project.

```
    ec -> ec.customizeMonoReply(
        (Message<?> message, Mono<?> mono) -> 
            mono.onErrorResume(
                WebClientResponseException.class,
                ex1 -> {
                    Mono<?> exReturn = mono;
                    if( ex1.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND ) {
                        exReturn = Mono.just(defaultPayload);
                    }
                    return (Mono)exReturn;
                }
            )
    )
```

While this works, it is not as clean as I would like. I am not thrilled with having to put an if condition in there to resolve the exception type by the `HttpStatus` rather than just resolve it to the specific class.

This might be a good candidate for a bug/enhancement.

Submitted [#3610](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3610)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it must be like this:

```
mono.onErrorResume(
    WebClientResponseException.class,
    ex1 -> Mono.just(ex1)
            .filter(ex -> ex.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
            .map(ex -> "default")
            .switchIfEmpty((Mono) mono))
```

The second argument of `onErrorResume()` is expected to be a `Function`, not a constant as you have so far.

Comment: I tried converting that over as you suggested but am getting:
`Type mismatch: cannot convert from Mono<Object> to Mono<? extends capture#3-of ?>`

Comment: Yeah... I see your point. That `Mono.just()` must be cast to `(Mono)`. See an edit to my answer. I see the fix for that `customizeMonoReply()` with generics. So, in the future version you won't need that `(Mono)` cast.

Comment: I just updated the code base on the referenced github - updating main post shortly. I want your take on how this is working.

Comment: See `.DefaultWebClientDefaultResponseSpec.statusHandlers`. Probably some other handler is somehow splipped in instead of `DEFAULT_STATUS_HANDLER`, which has that `ClientResponse::createException` callback for specific exception based on status. Or your status returned in some other format. This is what we need to debug. Probably your can share some simple project to play with.

Comment: See an edited code snippet how to avoid that `if..else` in your code.

Comment: Wow that `if..else` is something interesting! I am going to check the DefaultWebClient... bit you mentioned --- The source code for the project is linked on github in main post.

Comment: Thank you for the sample! Would you mind to add instruction how to run it and reproduce. I'll take a look next week then.

Comment: I found the location - `WebFluxRequestExecutingMessageHandler.exchangeForResponseMono()` line 314

Comment: Will provide instructions in repository this evening - look forward to your responses.

Comment: See the relevant generics fix: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/3612